# Factor polynomial of degree n+3

Tags: symbolic, polynomials, factorization

I'm considering a polynom poly[n,v] in v

```
poly[n_ , v_] := 5 (-1)^n + 2 v - 10 (-1)^n v - v^2 +5 (-1)^n v^2 + (-1 + 2 v)^(2 + n) (-5 + 4 v) +2 n (-1 + v) ((-1)^n (-1 + v) + (-1 + 2 v)^(2 + n))
```

for positive integers n.

checking

```
Apply[PolynomialGCD,   Table[poly[n, v] // Simplify, {n, 0, 10}]  ]
(* 16 (-1 + v)^2 v *)
```

shows, that the list of polynomials seem to possess  a common factor `v(1-v)^2`

but unfortunately

```
Simplify[ Factor[poly[n, v]], {Element[n, Integers], n > 0}]
```

doesn't succeed.

Is there a tricky way to factor out   `v(1-v)^2` for arbitrary integer n?
Thanks!

Comment: Not quite what you are looking for: `Series[poly[n, v] / v (v - 1)^2) , {v, 0, 2}]` nicely gives a polynomial in v without negative exponents, so for any `n` the polynomial has this factor, and we have the first three coefficients after division.

Comment: Ok your observation is true for series-expansion around v=v0(arbitrary!) . Thanks!

Comment: Expanding on the comment by @FredSimons, if `poly[n, v]` is divisible by `(v (v - 1)^2)`, then `poly[n, v] / v (v - 1)^2)` must be a polynomial of order `n` in `v`. This is true only if `Simplify[SeriesCoefficient[poly[n, v]/(v (v - 1)^2), {v, 0, n + 1}], n ∈ Integers && n > 0]` is zero, and it is

Comment: @ bbgodfrey That's true, but the question remains: How to evaluate the polynom(!) `poly[n, v] / (v (v - 1)^2))`? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may not be an "easy" way to factor `(v (1 - v)^2)` from `poly[n, v]`, leaving an `n`-th order polynomial.  Here is a not-so-easy approach.  Begin by simplifying the form of `poly`, representing `(-1 + 2 v)^(2 + n)` by `t`.

```
eq1 = Collect[poly[n, v] /. (-1 + 2 v)^(2 + n) -> t, v, Simplify]
(* (5 + 2 n) ((-1)^n - t) + (2 - 10 (-1)^n - 4 (-1)^n n + 4 t + 2 n t) v 
   + (-1 + 5 (-1)^n + 2 (-1)^n n) v^2 *)
```

Now, `t` can be expanded by the Binomial Theorem

```
Hold[Sum[Binomial[n + 2, k] (-1)^(n + 2 - k) (2 v)^k, {k, 0, n + 2}]];
```

which can be rewritten as

```
2 v Hold[Sum[Binomial[n + 2, k] (-1)^(n + 2 - k) (2 v)^(k - 1), {k, 1, n + 2}]] 
    + Sum[Binomial[n + 2, k] (-1)^(n + 2 - k) (2 v)^k, {k, 0, 0}];
```

which, when inserted into `eq1`, yields

```
eq2 = Collect[eq1 /. ((-1)^n - t) -> ((-1)^(n + 2) - %), {v, t}, Simplify]
(* (-1 + 5*(-1)^n + 2*(-1)^n*n)*v^2 + v*(2 - 10*(-1)^n - 4*(-1)^n*n + 2*(2 + n)*t - 
   2*(5 + 2*n)*Hold[Sum[Binomial[n + 2, k]*(-1)^(n + 2 - k)*(2*v)^(k - 1), 
   {k, 1, n + 2}]]) *)
```

thereby factoring out `v`.  Next, divide out that factor of `v` and replace `v` elsewhere by `x+1`.

```
eq3 = Collect[Cancel[eq2/v] /. v -> x + 1, {x, t}, Simplify]
(* 1 - 5*(-1)^n - 2*(-1)^n*n + 2*(2 + n)*t + (-1 + 5*(-1)^n + 2*(-1)^n*n)*x 
   - 2*(5 + 2*n)*Hold[Sum[Binomial[n + 2, k]*(-1)^(n + 2 - k)*(2*(1 + x))^(k - 1), 
   {k, 1, n + 2}]] *)
```

Again, expand `t` by the Binomial Theorem, this time in terms of `x`.

```
Hold[Sum[Binomial[n + 2, k] (2 x)^k, {k, 0, n + 2}]];
```

which can be rewritten as

```
(2 x)^2 Hold[Sum[Binomial[n + 2, k] (2 x)^(k - 2), {k, 2, n + 2}]] + 
    Sum[Binomial[n + 2, k] (2 x)^k, {k, 0, 1}]
(* 1 + 2*(2 + n)*x + 
   4*x^2*Hold[Sum[Binomial[n + 2, k]*(2*x)^(k - 2), {k, 2, n + 2}]] *)
```

which, when inserted into `eq3`, yields

```
eq7 = Collect[eq3 /. t -> %, x, Simplify]
(* (5 + 2*n)*(3 + (-1)^n + 2*n)*x + 8*(2 + n)*x^2*
   Hold[Sum[Binomial[n + 2, k]*(2*x)^(k - 2), {k, 2, n + 2}]] - 
   (5 + 2*n)*(-1 + (-1)^n + 2*Hold[Sum[Binomial[n + 2, k]*(-1)^(n + 2 - k)*
   (2*(1 + x))^(k - 1), {k, 1, n + 2}]]) *)
```

The second `Sum` is in powers of `1 + x`, and we need it in powers of `x`.  Once again, the Binomial Theorem facilitates this transformation, replacing `(1 + x))^(k - 1)` by

```
Hold[Sum[Binomial[k - 1, kk] x^kk, {kk, 0, k - 1}]];
```

which allows the second `Sum` in `eq7` to be rewritten as

```
eq4 = 2 Hold[Sum[Binomial[n + 2, k] (-1)^(n + 2 - k) 2^(k - 1) 
    Binomial[k - 1, kk] x^kk, {k, 1, n + 2}, {kk, 0, k - 1}]];
```

Interchanging the order of the two indices, `k` and `kk`, then gives

```
eq5 = 2 Hold[Sum[Binomial[n + 2, k] Binomial[k - 1, kk] (-1)^(n + 2 - k)
    2^(k - 1) x^kk, {kk, 0, n + 1}, {k, kk + 1, n + 2}]];
```

Because this interchange tends to be error-prone, it is prudent to verify that the two expressions are the same (here for n == 5).

```
Simplify[ReleaseHold[eq4 == eq5] /. n -> 5]
(* True *)
```

Next, explicitly perform the inner sum.

```
Sum[Binomial[n + 2, k] Binomial[k - 1, kk] (-1)^(n + 2 - k)
    2^(k - 1) x^kk, {k, kk + 1, n + 2}]
(* (-1)^(1 - kk + n) 2^kk x^kk Binomial[2 + n, 1 + kk] 
   Hypergeometric2F1[1 + kk, -1 + kk - n, 2 + kk, 2] *)
```

and insert the result into the outer `Sum`.

```
eq6 = 2 Hold[Sum[(-1)^(1 - kk + n) (2 x)^kk Binomial[2 + n, 1 + kk] 
    Hypergeometric2F1[1 + kk, -1 + kk - n, 2 + kk, 2], {kk, 0, n + 1}]];
ReleaseHold[eq5 == eq6]
(* True *)
```

`eq6` can be rewritten as

```
2 (2 x)^2 Hold[Sum[(-1)^(1 - kk + n) (2 x)^(kk - 2) Binomial[2 + n, 1 + kk] 
    Hypergeometric2F1[1 + kk, -1 + kk - n, 2 + kk, 2], {kk, 3, n + 1}]] + 
2 Sum[(-1)^(1 - kk + n) (2 x)^kk Binomial[2 + n, 1 + kk] 
    Hypergeometric2F1[1 + kk, -1 + kk - n, 2 + kk, 2], {kk, 0, 2}];
```

and inserted into `eq7`.

```
eq7 /. 2 Hold[_] -> %
eq8 = Collect[%/x^2, x, Simplify[#, n ∈ Integers] &] /. x -> v - 1
(* 8*(2 + n)*Hold[Sum[Binomial[n + 2, k]*(2*(-1 + v))^(k - 2), {k, 2, n + 2}]] - 
   (5 + 2*n)*(1 + (-1)^(1 + n) + 4*n + 2*n^2 + 
   8*Hold[Sum[(-1)^(1 - kk + n)*(2*(-1 + v))^(kk - 2)*Binomial[2 + n, 1 + kk]*
   Hypergeometric2F1[1 + kk, -1 + kk - n, 2 + kk, 2], {kk, 3, n + 1}]]) *)
```

Note that `x^2 == (v - 1)^2` has been factored from `eq8`, and **eq8 is the desired remainder**.  As verification,

```
Simplify[ReleaseHold[eq8 /. n -> 15] == poly[15, v]/(v (1 - v)^2)]
(* True *)
```

Incidentally, Mathematica diligently performs the general `Sum`s in `eq8`, if `Hold` is removed, but the resulting expression is not a step in the right direction.

Comment: You've done a tough job, thank you. Likely I need an undefined amount of time to understand(!) it.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the solution is simple. Form a differential equation for the reminder and solve it:

```
f = x (1 - x)^2 g[x];
lhs=D[f, {x, 3}]
rhs=D[poly[k, x], {x, 3}]
DSolve[lhs==rhs, g, x]
```

General solution for the reminder is given by

$\frac{c_1}{(x-1)^2 x}+\frac{c_2}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{c_3 x}{2 (x-1)^2}+\frac{(2 k x-2 k+4 x-5) (2 x-1)^{k+2}}{(x-1)^2 x}$

It is a simple matter to determine the constants. For instance, using `SolveAlways` for $k=1$ yields

```
SolveAlways[(2 (7 + C[1] + x (-48 + 8 x (15 + 2 x (-8 + 3 x)) + C[2])) 
             + x^2 C[3])/(2 (-1 + x)^2 x) == 16 (3 x - 2), x]
```

$c_1\to -7,c_2\to 16,c_3\to -16$.

Concerns were raised that in order to determine the coefficients we need to know the solution beforehand. However, the are nod actually needed. The polynomials can be computed setting $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$

```
v[k_, x_] := (-1 + 2 x)^(2 + k) (-5 - 2 k + 4 x + 2 k x)
PolynomialQuotient[v[10, x], (1 - x)^2 x , x]
```

Comment: It appears that you need to know the remainder in advance in order to obtain the coefficients, and the coefficients are different for each value of `k`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey The point is that you do not actually need to know the coefficients :) See my edit !

Comment: `PolynomialQuotient` discards any remainder.  To have no remainder, use `PolynomialQuotient[poly[10, v], (1 - v)^2 v, v]`, which would be equivalent to John Doty's `Cancel[poly[10, v]/(v (1 - v)^2)] `.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes, I know what `PolynomialQuotient` is doing. Yes, it looks like going in circles, however, there are some differences: the form of  the denominator is much simpler now showing also what terms are relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I think the clever analysis of @FredSimons needs to be made into an answer. @bbgodfrey's virtuoso algebra is impressive. However, since neither seems to yield a useful expression for general `n`, here's a simpler, (you might say stupider) solution:

```
rat3[n_Integer, v_Symbol] := Cancel[poly[n, v]/(v (1 - v)^2)]    
Table[rat3[n, v], {n, 0, 5}] // TableForm

16
16 (-2+3 v)
16 (4-9 v+8 v^2)
16 (-6+21 v-32 v^2+20 v^3)
16 (9-39 v+88 v^2-100 v^3+48 v^4)
32 (-6+33 v-96 v^2+160 v^3-144 v^4+56 v^5)
```